# mySQL trying to create table with constraint foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have this simple code

```
create table transport (
CODE varchar (10),
TDATE date,
ID integer,
PNAME varchar (10),
primary key (CODE,TDATE,ID,PNAME) );

create table planes (
NAME varchar (10),
NSEATS integer,
FSEATS integer,
ECSEATS integer,
primary key (NAME), 
CONSTRAINT foreign key(NAME) references transport(PNAME));
```

But it doesn't let me do the foreign key thing as it says errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Any tips appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The use of composite primary keys in this case is not reasonable.  If you want a foreign key reference, you need to reference *all* columns in the primary key.  So, this version is simpler:

```
create table transport (
    transportId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    CODE varchar (10),
    TDATE date,
    ID integer,
    PNAME varchar (10),
    unique (CODE, TDATE, ID, PNAME)
);

create table planes (
    planeId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    NAME varchar (10),
    NSEATS integer,
    FSEATS integer,
    ECSEATS integer,
    primary key (NAME), 
    transportId int,
    CONSTRAINT foreign key(transportId) references transport(transportId)
);
```

Comment: the thing is, that there are other tables that have foreign keys to the table transport. That's why it has the composite primary key. I just didn't post all of them in my attempt to make the problem as small as possible.

Comment: @NicolasNicolas . . . The more tables that have foreign key references to `transport`, the more useful a single primary key is as compared to a composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Rule is that : A Foreign key in one table points to a Primary Key in another table.